# RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCBlas.cu:450

Tags: pytorch, multiple-gpu

My program works properly with two GPUs but raise this error when reached to torch.bmm

```
energy =  torch.bmm(proj_query,proj_key) # transpose check

RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCBlas.cu:450
```

how could I solve this issue ?

Comment: check this link https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/20860